# How to model an interaction in a propensity-score matched dataset

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, propensity-scores, matching

Suppose I am performing a propensity score matched analysis using the `MatchIt` package in R, following the example reported here: https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html

```
library("MatchIt")
#Create dataset 'd' as reported at the bottom of the example----
gen_X <- function(n) {
  X <- matrix(rnorm(9 * n), nrow = n, ncol = 9)
  X[,5] <- as.numeric(X[,5] < .5)
  X
}
#~20% treated
gen_A <- function(X) {
  LP_A <- - 1.2 + log(2)*X[,1] - log(1.5)*X[,2] + log(2)*X[,4] - log(2.4)*X[,5] + log(2)*X[,7] - log(1.5)*X[,8]
  P_A <- plogis(LP_A)
  rbinom(nrow(X), 1, P_A)
}

# Continuous outcome
gen_Y_C <- function(A, X) {
  2*A + 2*X[,1] + 2*X[,2] + 2*X[,3] + 1*X[,4] + 2*X[,5] + 1*X[,6] + rnorm(length(A), 0, 5)
}

gen_Y_B <- function(A, X) {
  LP_B <- -2 + log(2.4)*A + log(2)*X[,1] + log(2)*X[,2] + log(2)*X[,3] + log(1.5)*X[,4] + log(2.4)*X[,5] + log(1.5)*X[,6]
  P_B <- plogis(LP_B)
  rbinom(length(A), 1, P_B)
}

gen_Y_S <- function(A, X) {
  LP_S <- -2 + log(2.4)*A + log(2)*X[,1] + log(2)*X[,2] + log(2)*X[,3] + log(1.5)*X[,4] + log(2.4)*X[,5] + log(1.5)*X[,6]
  sqrt(-log(runif(length(A)))*2e4*exp(-LP_S))
}

set.seed(19599)

n <- 2000
X <- gen_X(n)
A <- gen_A(X)

Y_C <- gen_Y_C(A, X)
Y_B <- gen_Y_B(A, X)
Y_S <- gen_Y_S(A, X)

d <- data.frame(A, X, Y_C, Y_B, Y_S)


#Create a toy column for an example treatment variable
set.seed(1145)
d$treatment <- sample.int(2, length(d$A), replace=TRUE)
d$treatment <- factor(d$treatment, levels=c(1,2), labels=c("Treatment A","Treatment B"))


#Matching----

    mF <- matchit(A ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + 
                     X6 + X7 + X8 + X9, data = d,
                   method = "full", estimand = "ATT")
    md <- match.data(mF)
```

Now suppose I have another variable, namely `treatment`, and that I want to perform a Cox-regression analysis to investigate whether there is an interaction between the effect of `treatment` and the `A` variable, on the risk of outcome (i.e. if the effect of `treatments` differs across the levels of `A` after matching). I read the "Moderation Analysis" section in the page linked above, but I am not sure the following is applicable under that context/it is formally correct, so I am asking.

My attempt would be:

```
library("survival")
coxph(Surv(Y_S) ~ A*treatment, data = md, robust = TRUE, 
      weights = weights, cluster = subclass)
```

The output is the following:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Y_S) ~ A * treatment, data = md, weights = weights, 
    robust = TRUE, cluster = subclass)

                           coef exp(coef) se(coef) robust se      z        p
A                       0.52453   1.68967  0.07818   0.11519  4.553 5.28e-06
treatmentTreatment B    0.17025   1.18560  0.05142   0.10742  1.585    0.113
A:treatmentTreatment B -0.17577   0.83881  0.10831   0.16196 -1.085    0.278

Likelihood ratio test=67.88  on 3 df, p=1.211e-14
n= 2000, number of events= 2000
```

Now the questions:

- **Question 1:** Is this approach to model the interaction **treatment*A** correct? Can I model an interaction *after* I have done the matching (obviously without matching for the treatment variable)?
- **Question 2:** Can I interpret the coefficients reported in the output as the *conditional effect* of treatment on the outcome, and interpret the interaction as I would do in a 'standard' non-matched Cox-regression model?